# Bayes' theorem when conditional and joint are merged

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vRv9.jpg)

I tried to apply bayes' theorem to the whole joint probability,
but I couldn't reach the right term.

Is there a special way to apply bayes' theorem to this kind of probability (conditional probability of somthing given joint of other two variables) ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Ok. I edited my question.

Comment: Everything is conditioned on $x_0$, so you're effectively in a new probability space where $p(...)=q(...|x_0)$.